# Listen the track at faster speed in Amarok

Tags: amarok

I want to listen to my audio/track at 2x speed than usual but I'm unable to find any option to make it happen in the Amarok player. Is there any way to do it either with the Amarok player or from the terminal?

I am using Opensuse 13.2 OS and Amarok Version 2.8.0 Using KDE 4.14.9

Comment: Don't know with amarok, but you may install and use `mplayer` from the commandline (double the speed with key `}`, or `vlc` which has the option to change the replay speed.

Comment: Changing the software is one way but it would be great if we can configure Amarok to achieve the goal.

Comment: It seems unlikely that amarok would be able to do this.